# Pandas - appending to existing file using to_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to append a df to an existing file using the following code:

```
with open(file, 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=False)
    f.close()
```

This almost gives me what I want, except that when I open the file, every record that was added is followed by a blank line, before the next valid record appears.

I have seen similar questions, but they were using built-in Python functions as opposed to pandas' to_csv.

Comment: I can't reproduce such a beheaviour. Can you give us a reproducible example. Maybe your data contains newlines? Also [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) allows you to set the mode directly with the mode parameter.

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I specify the mode directly in the to_csv call, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use directly the pandas API for appending to the csv:

```
df.to_csv(file, header=False, mode='a')
```